# moving every int in the array one place backwards

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move every int in array one "cell" (position) backwards (and take the first int to the last position) in a `for` loop. (*example: if i have array of `5,6,9` the result will be `6,9,5`*).

Here is my code:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int temp=arr[0];
for (int i=1; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
{
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
}
arr[arr.Length - 1] = temp;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```

Instead of getting

> `2,3,4,5,6,1`

I'm getting

> `2,3,4,5,5`.

Why is my code not working? What is the right way to do such process?

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: You can then step through the code at run time and inspect the values of variables and fields. That should enable you to see why your code does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: I don't get the down vote. The question has everything it needs. The entire code to reproduce the problem the given output and the expected. I wonder what people sometimes expect?!

Comment: Also, **do the algorithm on a piece of paper**.  Write out the array on a piece of paper, and then run your algorithm *by hand* on the paper array. **Do what the code says, not what you think the code says**. You will quickly see what you are doing wrong.  Next **solve the problem correctly on your paper array**, making notes about everything you are doing as you are doing it. Then translate your notes into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-1` :

```
for (int i=1; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
```

in both loops and let the loops run until the end. The condition should be `i < arr.Length` You never reach the last position.

Although you use `arr[arr.Length - 1]` to Index the last element, it is different with the loop. If you take a closer look at the finishing condition it says: `<` that means that `i` will never get the value of `Length - 1` the loop will end one iteration before that. Another way to fix your code would be to change the condition and let `i` run until it gets this value. You can achieve it by: `i <= arr.Length - 1`. The little difference should also do the trick. This time the loop will end exactly after I has reached the value of the index of the last element

Comment: result after your solution is 23456. there is still not a "1" in the end

Comment: You have two loops to fix

Comment: @Steve the line after the first loop should take care of the one. I am confused...

Comment: The OP display the values using a loop with the same error _< Length-1;_ All the values are in the correct position but he doesn't show all 6 elements only 5

Comment: @Steve This is why I used the plural "loops". I hope I made it clearer with my last edit

Comment: @MongZhu I was replying to the OP comment. Your solution is fine

Answer (score 2):

This code does what you need. Sort the array.

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
//int[] arr = { 5, 6, 9 }; 
//string[] arr = { "A", "B", "C" }; 

var result = Enumerable.Range(1, arr.Length).Select(i => arr[i % arr.Length]).ToArray();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Input data and Results:

```
//Input: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
//Result: 2,3,4,5,6,1

//Input: { 5, 6, 9 };
//Result: 6,9,5

//Input: { "A", "B", "C" }; 
//Result: B,C,A
```

Comment: Would this same code work for a different source array?

Comment: Clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the `- 1` from your for loop condition, as it is not iterating over all the elements in your array.

If iterating over an array of 6 elements, the indices are from 0 -> 5. So, for your example, you want your loop to go from index 1 to 5 (what you *had* been doing is iterating over indices 1-4 (since you were subtracting by 1).

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int temp=arr[0];
for (int i=1; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
}

arr[arr.Length - 1] = temp;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```